# Спрыгивание персонажа вниз с Platform Effector 2D Unity

Tags: unity3d, 2d, физика

Unity, 2D платформер с видом сбоку.

Игрок стоит на объекте, на который запрыгивает снизу вверх, использую Platform Effector 2D.

Как при нажатии на "Вниз"+"Пробел" сделать так, чтобы игрок спрыгнул вниз, при этом, все остальные игроки остались на платформе?

При этом, игрок при падении с платформы должен взаимодействовать с другими объектами, такими же игроками, противниками, пулями и т.п.

Comment: убрать коллайдер игрока на время?

Comment: Тогда он не получит урон, если будет лететь пуля сквозь него. Или отталкивающий молот)

Comment: Вы бы добавили все условия в вопрос..

Comment: Предыдущий оратор абсолютно прав - Вы бы глянули https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Слой сменить у колайдера игрока, чтоб он перестал тригериться только с объектами окружения. [`GameObject-layer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-layer.html).
2. Заигнорить временно взаимодействие некоторых слоёв с помощью [`Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision.html).